# On demand encoding of raw video with gstreamer and python

Tags: python, video-streaming, gstreamer, video-processing

I'm working on a video processing and distribution server based on gstreamer and python. I have several incoming compressed video streams which I pass between pipelines by using mpegtsmux add multifdsink elements. So when I see that particular stream is not used anymore I can send an EOS event to certain pipeline. That is a main idea of how I'm keeping it on-demand. However when in comes to handling raw video things get nasty very fast.

In ideal world I would like to have 1 decoder pipeline which would feed other with raw video for various detectors and encoders. So until now I've tried 3 options:

1. Multifdsink / raw video

Main decoder :

fdsrc ! tsdemux ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! videorate !  multifidsink

Sample encoder (Separate pipeline):

fdsrc ! rawvideoparse use-sink-caps=1 ! "caps from multifdsink inserted here" ! videoconvert ! videorate ! videoscale ! x264enc tune=zerolatency key-int-max=5 ! mpegtsmux ! multifdsink

This way I can start/stop encoders at ease but I get a color mess of a picture no mater what caps do multifdsink provide

2. Multiudpsink / raw video

Main decoder:

fdsrc ! tsdemux ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! videorate !  rtpvrawpay ! multiudpsink

Sample encoder (Separate pipeline):

udpsrc caps="caps from multiudpsink inserted here" ! rtpvrawdepay ! videoconvert ! videorate ! videoscale ! x264enc tune=zerolatency key-int-max=5 ! mpegtsmux ! multifdsink

This way I can start/stop encoders at ease. I even get a nice picture when there's little motion on the scene, but when motion is introduced I get a lot of artifacts like missing parts of walking man. Not to mention that I get 50Mbit of network trafic on lo for a single 320X240 stream

3. Dynamic pipelines usage

(Mostly inspired by https://github.com/MaZderMind/dynamic-gstreamer-pipelines-cookbook/blob/master/05-add-and-remove-network-sink.py)

Main decoder:

fdsrc ! tsdemux ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! videorate !  tee

Sample encoder (Gst.Bin):

queue ! videoconvert ! videorate ! videoscale !  x264enc tune=zerolatency key-int-max=5 ! mpegtsmux ! multifdsink

```
    # code to add encoder to running pipeline 
    self.motion_debug = self.create_encoder_pipeline('motion', encoder='h264')
    self.pipeline.add(self.motion_debug)
    tee = self.pipeline.get_by_name('motion_tee')
    print(tee.link(self.motion_debug))
    self.motion_debug.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
```

```
    #code to remove encoder from running pipeline   
    ghostpad = self.motion_debug.get_static_pad("sink")
    teepad = ghostpad.get_peer()
    teepad.add_probe(Gst.PadProbeType.BLOCK, self.blocking_pad_probe)
   
    def blocking_pad_probe(self,pad, info):
        print("Stopping Bin")
        self.motion_debug.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)


        tee = self.pipeline.get_by_name('motion_tee')
        ghostpad = self.motion_debug.get_static_pad("sink")
        teepad = ghostpad.get_peer()

        print('Removing encoder bin')
        print(self.pipeline.remove(self.motion_debug))

        print("Releasing Tee-Pad")
        tee.release_request_pad(teepad)

        self.motion_debug = None
        return Gst.PadProbeReturn.REMOVE
```

Here I start the main decoder and on demand add a Gst.Bin containing sample encoder. First time (no encoder was requested yet) I can get a stream with visible delay of 1-2 seconds. But when encoder get stopped and detached from pipeline on the next demand I get a still frame with players actually indicate time ticking (encoder pushes the same frame all over again). So for the viewer it looks like frozen picture being received time and time again while video is playing.

I believe that the most right way to solve my problem would be the 3rd approach. But I welcome any solution or thought.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was simple: `videorate` element can sometime push the same frame to achieve  desired FPS. Use `viderate.set_property('drop-only', True)` to avoid such a behavior.